# Using the replace function in Netsuite for components in assemblies

Tags: netsuite

Very new to Netsuite. I'm trying to use a saved item search to find all instances of {componentitem} entry is 800484 and replace them with component 516551302688

I'm using the REPLACE function in the saved item search but it doesn't like my formula REPLACE(800484, [, 516551302688]){componentitem}

I'm sure I am doing something wrong in the formula but unsure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

The function signature for `REPLACE` is:

```
REPLACE(char, search_string, replacement_string)
```

`char` is the text to search in.

`search_string` is the text to search for.

`replacement_string` is the text to replace the `search_string` with, where found.

What you have appears to be more like

```
REPLACE(search_string, replacement_string)char
```

The text you want to search in is outside of the function altogether (outside the parentheses that enclose what the function will act on).  You also have additional brackets and a comma in your formula.

Based you the information in your question, your formula should be

```
REPLACE({componentitem}, '800484', '516551302688')
```

I have wrapped the search and replacement strings in quotes as `REPLACE` deals with strings.  If you leave the quotes off, the database will infer the string values of the numbers given and it will still work, but it's best practice to be explicit.

Note that this will only replace the values within the results of the saved search, and will have no effect on the underlying records.  Hopefully you already know this, but I just mention it as the wording of your question makes it appear as if you're expecting it to substitute the actual components.

HTH.

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and it's good to know I was close to getting the formula correct but it still tells me that it has an unrecognizable field in the formula.

I'm assuming it means the componentitem field, which could be incorrect as I'm still learning Netsuite and the names of the fields.

You say what I'm doing will just replace the values, not the underlying records. Could you please expand on this, as I am looking to make it swap the actual components and this was the easiest way I could think of.

Comment: To make sure you have a valid field, create an item saved search in the UI and add a Formula field under results.  Then click the "popup" button beside the formula entry input and select the field you want from the field selection dropdown.  This will add a field id wrapped in braces to the formula edit pane.   Any field that can be added from that dropdown *should* be a valid field.  I suspect the field you want is `memberitem` rather than `componentitem`.

Comment: Adding this formula will only affect the results displayed in the saved search.  It will not affect the underlying records.  To change the underlying records, you could export the results you get and then run a CSV import which would make the changes.

Comment: Again, thank you for all your help.
It doesn't seem like the replace function will do what I want. Unfortunately we're not allowed to use the import/export function as we haven't been trained on it yet and the department head is worried we will mess things up.
We have been hand fixing them, and will be finishing it Monday, but I am going to push for Import/Export training to prevent this in the future.